# How to Transfer a Log file to Microsoft SQL server management DB table

Tags: sql-server, cursor, mirth

I am trying to transfer a Log file, specifically from Mirth. Into, a SQL Server database table (MirthTable_L). I am rather new the SQL Server. I have tried BULK INSERT and it doesn't seem to go through. I do believe I am inserting it correctly, I was told I may need a File Reader that loops, and reads row-by-row. Any beginner examples on how to do such would help immensely! Thanks.

Comment: what is the file type of your log file? from it there are many classes you can use (reader, streams etc.)

Comment: Text Document (.log)